# Boost ASIO connect failing

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, boost, boost-asio

I want to do a simple C++ web get using boost asio

I started by using this as an example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

but I keep getting messages like this

> Connect failed: No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it

Comment: isn't `verify_client_once` a server-side option? I've always used the option `default_workarounds` on the client which has worked.

Comment: I changed it to use verify_peer like the example and added the default_workarounds option like you suggested but still I see the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing, the issue was a typo in the hostname. When referencing an invalid hostname you can get this error message:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

Putting this answer here in case someone else encounters the same bone headed mistake